# I got error The page isn't redirecting properly

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I wrote:

```
    RewriteRule ^pu/([0-9]+)/? post_pu.php?id=$1 [L]
```

It works, but when I added:

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/post_pu\.php$
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pu/%1/? [R=301,L]
```

I got error: "The page isn't redirecting properly" on page http://11klassniki.ru/pu/1

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^pu/([0-9]+)/? post_pu.php?id=$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/post_pu\.php$
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pu/%1/? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I try to redict from http://11klassniki.ru/post_pu.php?id_pu=1 to http://11klassniki.ru/pu/1

Comment: I found error it sopposed to be RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id_pu=([0-9]+)$

Comment: No. I was wrong. I still have "The page isn't redirecting properly" RewriteRule ^pu/([0-9]+)/? post_pu.php?id_pu=$1 [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/post_pu\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id_pu=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pu/%1/? [R=301,L]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)$
```